# Valid CoreOS multi tenancy scenario?

Tags: docker, coreos

I'm currently tinkering with a scenario for using CoreOS. It's probably not the 1st class use case. But I'd like to get a pointer if it's valid though. As I'm really at the beginning of getting a grip on CoreOS I hope that my "use case" is not totally off.

Imagine a multi tenant application where every tenant should get it's own runtime environment. Let's take a web app running on Node.js and PostgreSQL for data storage as given. Each tenant environment would be be running on CoreOS in their respective containers. Data persistance is left out for now. For me it's currently more about the general feasibility.

So why CoreOS?

Currently I try to stick with the idea of separated environments per tenant. To optimise the density of DB and web server instances per hardware host I thought CoreOS might be the right choice instead of "classic" virtualisation.

Another reason is that a lot of tenants might not need more than a single, smallish DB instance and a single, smallish web server. But there might be other tenants that need some constantly scaled out deployments. Others might need a temporary scale out during burst times. CoreOS sounds like a good fit here as well.

On the other side there must be a scalable messaging infrastructure (RabbitMQ) in behind that will handle a lot of messages. This infrastructure will be used by all tenants and needs to dynamically scalable at best. Probably there will be a "to be scaled" Elasticsearch infrastructure as well. Viewed through my current "CoreOS for everything goggles" this seems a good fit as well.

In case this whole scenario is generally valid, I currently cannot see how it would be possible to route the traffic for a general available web site to the different tenant containers.

Imagine the app is running at app.greatthing.tld. A user can login and should be presented the app served for it's tenant. Is this something socketplane and/or flannel are there to solve? Or how would a solution look like to get the tenant served by the right containers? I think it's kind of a general issue. But at least in the context of a CoreOS containerized environment I cannot see how to deal with this at all.

Comment: Given the multi-tennant nature and the fact that Docker isn't yet considered fully secure, I'd also like to point out SmartOS as an alternative. https://smartos.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your main issue is routing. You'd need to configure some sort of routing layer that is the entry point into the cluster, reads the host header and forwards the traffic on to the appropriate container(s). A common way to do this is confd + nginx running in a container.

The second part of this is to have your backend containers "announce" themselves, aka write some data in etcd when they are active and have passed their health checks. This allows you to move around the backends as you deploy new versions, scale up, etc.

So how do you deploy this? First, check out the [cluster architectures](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/cluster-architectures.html#production-cluster-with-central-services) doc. I'd take a subset of your machines and place them behind a cloud LB (or do round robin DNS) that points to your routing containers running on 80/443. These then forward traffic infra-cluster to the appropriate backend.

There is no need to use flannel or other networking projects if you are just storing the IP/port combo of the backend to connect to.